# Add-in with predefined shortcut key?

Tags: vba, excel

Firstly, this is all in Excel 2007, FYI.

I'm trying to set up an Add-in that will use a shortcut key to run a simple macro.  I want to define that shortcut key so that I can simply tell my users to press "ctl+alt+l" to run the macro, hopefully keeping explanations to a minimum on my team since the user interface would be unified.

My code to set up the shortcut key is right here:

```
Sub LiteralizeShortcutKey()

    Application.OnKey "%^l", "Literalize"

End Sub
```

When I run the macro it works just fine.

I then create a Workbook macro to autoload when the excel file opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    LiteralizeShortcutKey
End Sub
```

This works fine when I open the workbook.  But it all falls apart when I export the workbook to a .xlam and then load it into another workbook.  My little LiteralizeShortcutKey() Sub won't load, so I can't use my predefined shortcut key.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the add-in activated? Or is just one Sub left out and others working?  Maybe "Disable all macros without notification" option turned on?

Comment: Yeah, it was.  I found an answer already, but the stack is making me wait until tomorrow to post it.  In a nutshell I had this code in the wrong place (ThisWorkbook) and it's more effective to use: Private Sub Woorkbook_AddinInstall than Workbook_Open.